# Combine Circletype.js with jQuery animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I want to use [Circletype.js](http://circletype.labwire.ca/) in conjunction with jQuery `.animate()` to cause text to curve around my logo/image as I animate the width of its container.

I am applying `.circleType({fluid:true});` to the `#demo4` div. This, along with the correct css, causes the text path to bend to fit its container (`#resize`).

**Run the code snippet** to illustrate:

1. text radius does change when container is resized manually
2. text radius does not change when resized via `.animate()`. **Why not?**

```js
  $(function() {
    $("#resize").resizable();
    $("#resize").draggable();
  });
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("#resize").animate({
      left: '50px',
      width: '650px'
    });
  });



  $('#demo4').circleType({
    fluid: true,
    dir: -1
  });
```

```css
 #resize {
   position: relative;
   width: 220px;
   height: auto;
   padding: 0.5em;
   border: 1px solid;
 }
 #resize h4 {
   text-align: center;
   margin: 0;
 }
 .demo-box {
   position: relative;
   max-width: 700px;
   margin: 10% auto;
   color: #476A50;
   background-color: #ccc;
 }
 #logo {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 44%;
   width: 60%;
   height: auto;
   margin-left: 23%;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.kernjs.com/js/lettering.js"></script>
<script src="http://circletype.labwire.ca/js/circletype.js"></script>
<button>Start Animation</button>
<div id="resize" class="ui-widget-content">
  <h4 class="ui-widget-header">Resize/Drag/Animate</h4>

  <div class="demo-box" id="demo-box4">
    <h2 id="demo4" class="demo strong">Anything in WordPress </h2>

    <img src="http://profondodesign.com/assets/images/pd-Logo-800x320.png" id="logo" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this though if you just want the end result. If you want the text to be also animated, then the below code won't work. See if it works for your requirement

```js
  $(function() {
    $("#resize").resizable();
    $("#resize").draggable();
    circleInit();
  });
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("#resize").animate({
      left: '50px',
      width: '650px'
    },400,'swing',function() { circleInit(); });
  });

 function circleInit() {
  $('#demo4').circleType({
    fluid: true,
    dir: -1
  });
}
```

```css
 #resize {
   position: relative;
   width: 220px;
   height: auto;
   padding: 0.5em;
   border: 1px solid;
 }
 #resize h4 {
   text-align: center;
   margin: 0;
 }
 .demo-box {
   position: relative;
   max-width: 700px;
   margin: 10% auto;
   color: #476A50;
   background-color: #ccc;
 }
 #logo {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 44%;
   width: 60%;
   height: auto;
   margin-left: 23%;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.kernjs.com/js/lettering.js"></script>
<script src="http://circletype.labwire.ca/js/circletype.js"></script>
<button>Start Animation</button>
<div id="resize" class="ui-widget-content">
  <h4 class="ui-widget-header">Resize/Drag/Animate</h4>

  <div class="demo-box" id="demo-box4">
    <h2 id="demo4" class="demo strong">Anything in WordPress </h2>

    <img src="http://profondodesign.com/assets/images/pd-Logo-800x320.png" id="logo" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code for circletype shows that the [text is only reflowed when the window is resized](https://github.com/peterhry/CircleType/blob/master/js/circletype.js#L141):

```
    if (settings.fluid && !settings.fitText) {
        $(window).resize(function () {
            layout();
        });
    }
```